# Not able to mock the method inside flask URL

Tags: unit-testing, flask, mocking

I written below url in flask

```
@app_url.route('/createvm', methods=['GET', 'POST'], defaults={'buildid': None})
def form(buildid):
    command = prepare_ansible_command(data)
    success,reason = run_command(command)
    # here run_coomand method not returning mock return value.
    ....
```

writing below unit test case

```
@patch('app.vm_create.utility.run_command')
def test_vm_create_negative3(self, run_command_mock):
    run_command_mock.return_value = True, "response123456"
    from app.vm_create.utility import run_command 
    #I checked run_command here it's returning mock return value (True, "response123456")
    with self.client:
        resp = self.client.post("/signin/", data={"username": self.act.username, 
                                "password": self.password, "token":True})
        resp= self.client.post("/createvm", data=data)
```

The run_commnad returning mocked return value inside test method.
It's not returning mock return value inside view function (createvm)
running the above test using pytest
pytest test_app.py -k "test_vm_create_negative3"

Answer (score 1):

Solved! This is what it was happening: `run_command()` function was implemented in `app.vm_create.utility.py`, but it was imported by `app.vm_create.controllers.py`. When I tried to mock `run_command` by patching `app.vm_create.utility.run_command` (in `utility` where it was implemented), it didn't work. However, this worked:

```
@patch("app.vm_create.controllers.run_command")
def test_etc:
    etc
```

As you can see, I'm still patching `run_command()`, but this time, with the path of the module which is importing it, `controllers`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).